# Comment character for ~/.byobu/windows.tmux file

Tags: byobu, tmux

Inserted the # hashmark character at the beginning of a line in   `~/.byobu/windows.tmux`.
Attempting to launch byobu results in error and it not launching at all.

```
user@machine ~ $ byobu
unknown command: #new-window
user@machine ~ $
```

Found this seven year old unanswered question on unix.stackexchange.com
[How to comment in a windows.tmux file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218127/how-to-comment-in-a-windows-tmux-file)

Fails with these comment characters `#` , `//` , and `;`

```
user@machine ~ $ cat ~/.byobu/windows.tmux
new-session -s 'FW';
new-window -n FireWall ssh -p 23 fwuser@FireWall;
new-window -n root sudo su - ;
new-window -n TTYrouter sudo minicom /dev/ttyUSB3 ; 
new-window -n untangle ssh root@untangle.localdomain ;
; new-window -n COMMENT ssh root@untangle.localdomain ;
new-window -n ; 
new-window -n rock64 ssh user@rock64;
new-window -n rock64root user@rock64 "sudo su -";
user@machine ~ $ byobu
```

- `;`  results in `no command`
- `#`  results in `unknown command: #`
- `//`  results in `unknown command: //`

Comment: Have you tried other common comment characters like `;` or `//`?

Comment: Did you try `# new-window` (adding a space between the comment and the command)?

Comment: @ArturMeinild, yes tried a spacebar character after each comment character.  Question reflects that now.

Comment: @mchid, yes i tried those as well and updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: You should probably report this as a bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/byobu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/byobu.1.html), 22.04 version:

> Users can create a list of windows to launch at startup in  `$BYOBU_CONFIG_DIR/windows`  and
> `$BYOBU_CONFIG_DIR/windows.tmux`.    This  file  is  the  same  syntax  as  `~/.screenrc`  and
> `~/.tmuxrc`, each line specifying a window, as described in screen(1) or tmux(1).

manual for screen, 22.04 version says: `#`:

> A  command's  arguments
> are  separated by tabs or spaces, and may be surrounded by single or double quotes.  A `#'
> turns the rest of the line into a comment, except in  quotes.   Unintelligible  lines  are
> warned  about  and ignored.

manual for [tmux](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/tmux.1.html), 22.04 version states: `#`:

> Comments are marked by the unquoted # character - any remaining text after a comment is
> ignored until the end of the line.

> Command arguments may be specified as strings surrounded by single (') quotes, double quotes
> (") or braces ({}).  This is required when the argument contains any special character.
> Single and double quoted strings cannot span multiple lines except with line continuation.
> Braces can span multiple lines.

So ... I would consider this a bug.